# GridBagLayout isn't formatting correctly

Tags: java, swing, debugging

I'm trying to get the config panel to take up the top of the screen, and then have the input and output panels side-by-side. I'm also trying to get the text areas to be 70 characters wide each and 30 rows tall. However, right now, the config panel isn't showing up at all, and the text areas are only 35 characters wide and 2 rows tall. I've followed all the examples and tutorials I've found. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class BorderWrapper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Border Wrapper");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create main panel
        MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //Display frame
        Dimension minSize = new Dimension(650, 375);
        frame.setPreferredSize(minSize);
        frame.setMinimumSize(minSize);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}



public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Font INPUT_FONT = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    private JTextArea inputArea, outputArea;
    private JTextField titleField, topBorderField, sideBorderField;

    public MainPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        //Set up config panel
        JPanel configPanel = new JPanel();
        configPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(configPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        configPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

        titleField      = new JTextField(25);
        titleField.setFont(INPUT_FONT);
        topBorderField  = new JTextField(1);
        topBorderField.setFont(INPUT_FONT);
        sideBorderField = new JTextField(4);
        sideBorderField.setFont(INPUT_FONT);

        configPanel.add(new JLabel("Title:"));
        configPanel.add(titleField);
        configPanel.add(new JLabel("Top border:"));
        configPanel.add(topBorderField);
        configPanel.add(new JLabel("Side border:"));
        configPanel.add(sideBorderField);

        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx     = 0;
        c.gridy     = 0;
        add(configPanel, c);

        //Set up Input panel
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        inputArea = new JTextArea("Type or paste your stuff here . . .");
        inputArea.setFont(INPUT_FONT);
        inputArea.setLineWrap(true);
        inputArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        inputArea.setColumns(75);
        JScrollPane inputPane = new JScrollPane(inputArea);
        inputPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 400));

        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel("Text Box");
        inputLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        inputPanel.add(inputLabel);
        inputPanel.add(inputPane);
        inputPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 400));

        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx     = 0;
        c.gridy     = 1;
        add(inputPanel, c);

        //Set up Output panel
        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
        outputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(outputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        outputArea = new JTextArea();
        outputArea.setFont(INPUT_FONT);
        outputArea.setLineWrap(true);
        outputArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        outputArea.setColumns(75);
        JScrollPane outputPane = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        outputPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 400));

        JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("Wrapped Output");
        outputLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        outputPanel.add(outputLabel);
        outputPanel.add(outputPane);
        outputPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 400));

        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx     = 1;
        c.gridy     = 1;
        add(outputPanel, c);
    }
}
```

Originally, I was going to try to use a BorderLayout, since it seemed that made the most sense for the layout I was trying to make, but that did an even worse job when I set them to BorderLayout.WEST and BorderLayout.EAST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have modified your program to use BorderLayout in the MainPanel and few other minor changes to get the desired look and feel.Check if this helps.

```
public class BorderWrapper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Border Wrapper");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create main panel
        MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        // Display frame
        Dimension minSize = new Dimension(650, 375);
        frame.setPreferredSize(minSize);
        frame.setMinimumSize(minSize);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Font INPUT_FONT = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    private JTextArea inputArea, outputArea;
    private JTextField titleField, topBorderField, sideBorderField;

    public MainPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Set up config panel
        JPanel configPanel = new JPanel();
        configPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(configPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        configPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

        titleField = new JTextField(25);
        titleField.setFont(INPUT_FONT);
        topBorderField = new JTextField(1);
        topBorderField.setFont(INPUT_FONT);
        sideBorderField = new JTextField(4);
        sideBorderField.setFont(INPUT_FONT);

        configPanel.add(new JLabel("Title:"));
        configPanel.add(titleField);
        configPanel.add(new JLabel("Top border:"));
        configPanel.add(topBorderField);
        configPanel.add(new JLabel("Side border:"));
        configPanel.add(sideBorderField);

        add(configPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Set up Input panel
        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        inputArea = new JTextArea("Type or paste your stuff here . . .");
        inputArea.setFont(INPUT_FONT);
        inputArea.setLineWrap(true);
        inputArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        inputArea.setColumns(75);
        JScrollPane inputPane = new JScrollPane(inputArea);

        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel("Text Box");
        inputLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        inputPanel.add(inputLabel);
        inputPanel.add(inputPane);

        lowerPanel.add(inputPanel);

        // Set up Output panel
        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
        outputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(outputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        outputArea = new JTextArea();
        outputArea.setFont(INPUT_FONT);
        outputArea.setLineWrap(true);
        outputArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        outputArea.setColumns(75);
        JScrollPane outputPane = new JScrollPane(outputArea);

        JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("Wrapped Output");
        outputLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        outputPanel.add(outputLabel);
        outputPanel.add(outputPane);

        lowerPanel.add(outputPanel);
        add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

[image]

I felt it convenient to use BorderLayout for this format.Anyways, you can still make few changes to the code you posted using GridBagConstraints to get the desired look.Make the below changes one by one and you will observe the differences.

1.You were aligning the MainPanel to the NORTH by using BorderLayout.But in your case the entire set of components is placed in MainPanel,so better place it in center.So instead of NORTH use below :(after this change,you will see the complete input and output panels)

```
MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

2.You have set the dimension of the Parent frame to Dimension(height=375)

```
minSize = new Dimension(650, 375);
```

You components(configPanel=200,outputPanel=400) combined height is more than 375.Increase the height of the Parent, to about 600.

3.Instead of BoxLayout try using GridLayout for configPanel.

```
configPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,6,5,0));
```

Making the above 3 changes to your existing code will get the expected output.Hope this clarifies.

Comment: This absolutely helps! However are you able to see what went wrong with my original code with the GridBagLayout as to why it's not working? I'd really like to learn how to use it if I can. It just doesn't make sense why it wasn't working the way I had it.

Comment: Please see the above edited answer(using GridBagLayout).Hope that will help you.